# Which URLs need to be whitelisted for MacPorts to work behind a proxy?

Tags: macos, proxy, macports

I can use only allowed web resources via corporate proxy and to add something new to that list I should know a URL pattern, e.g. `https://*developer.apple.com/*`

What URLs need to be whitelisted for MacPorts to work?

Comment: @Tonny Sure – I absolutely understand your point, but I can't bend the rules in that case. We can migrate the question to [apple.SE] if it does not get too many views *and* if the OP requests it, though.

Comment: @shlck Point taken. Let's see what happens.